# AngularJS $modalInstance - Can i do this in one controller?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, bootstrap-modal

I've spent some time having a play with the AngularJS Bootstrap popup, and for intents it's working great, but what i'd like to do is bind it, and it's dependant script to the same controller, what i can't get working is the close button now though. If i create a NEW controller, and inject $modalInstance it works great and i can wireup the close button without any issues at all, but i don't want a second controller, it seems to be over complication: i want all my controller logic in the formController really.

Why would i actually want two controllers? Passing the scope between two controllers just seems overkill to me, and the larger a project becomes the more un-managable it will become. Am i trying to over-simplify this unnecessarily? :)

The script:

```
(function(){
    var app = angular.module('ngModalDemo', ['ui.bootstrap']) 
    .controller('formController', function($scope, $modal){
        $scope.openModal = function () {                        
            var modalInstance = $modal.open({
                templateUrl: 'SomeModal.html',
                controller: 'formController'                                            
            });
        };
        $scope.closeModal = function () {
            //  Code needed here :)
        };
    })
})();
```

The HTML body (excuse the HTML in script for the purposes of the DEMO):

```
    <div ng-controller="formController">
        <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="openModal()">Let's do some stuff!</button>

        <script type="text/ng-template" id="SomeModal.html">
            <div class="modal-header">Do some stuff in this modal y'all.</div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button class="btn btn-info" ng-click="closeModal()">Close</button>
            </div>
        </script>
    </div>
```

The answer based on Kaspars' input :)

```
    (function(){
            var app = angular.module('ngModalDemo', ['ui.bootstrap']) 
            .controller('formController', function($scope, $modal, $log){
                $scope.openModal = function () {                        
                    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
                        templateUrl: 'SomeModal.html',
                        controller: [
                            '$scope', '$modalInstance', function($scope, $modalInstance){
                                $scope.closeModal = function () {
                                    $modalInstance.close();
                                };
                            }
                        ]                           
                    });
                };
            })
        })();
```

Comment: a separate modal controller works great, if the modal is going to be shared by many controllers

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was struggling with the same problem and the best thing I came up with was to use anonymous function as a modal controller. In that way all the logic is in the same controller and you don't have to create separate controller for each modal window.

This would look like this:

```
(function(){
    var app = angular.module('ngModalDemo', ['ui.bootstrap']) 
    .controller('formController', function($scope, $modal){
        $scope.openModal = function () {                        
            var modalInstance = $modal.open({
                templateUrl: 'SomeModal.html',
                controller: [
                    '$scope', '$modalInstance', 'data', function($scope, $modalInstance, data) {
                        $scope.data = data;
                        $scope.ok = function() {
                            $modalInstance.close();
                        };
                        $scope.closeModal = function() {
                            $modalInstance.dismiss();
                        };
                    }
                ]
            });
        };
    })
})();
```

PS. Haven't tested code above, just put it together from your provided code and fragments from one of my projects.

Comment: Thanks Kaspars, that worked a treat, i've added the actual code which i've simplified for reference to the original question :)

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this

```
    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
                                templateUrl : 'someTemplate.html',
                                scope : $scope,
                                size : 'md'
                            });
```