# Reset form fields outside a controller in AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am having problem with resetting signup modal form fields.

For example, I have called a custom resetForm function when the user click modal close button and after getting $http request.

```
$scope.resetForm = function () {
            $scope.successMessage = "";
            $scope.message = "";

            $scope.FPEmail = "";
            $scope.forgotForm.$setPristine();
        };
```

But the bootstrap modals have property of getting close by clicking outside the modal body. In this case, I am not able to resetForm. I have tried to resolve it by putting ng-click on the button by which I am opening the modal. But this button is situated outside the controller and I don't know how to reset the form from outside the controller.

Comment: How do you close modal right now?

Comment: if you want that modal should nt be closed after clicking outside then add this  data-backdrop="static" to div class="modal fade "  data-backdrop="static">

Comment: Do you have a specific controller attached with model ?

Comment: there are two ways to close it. 1) by clicking on close button (X) and 2) by  clicking outside the modal

Comment: @Anita I need to use both modal closing properties

Comment: @SatyamKoyani I have specific controllers on modals but I don't have any controller from where I am opening the modal.

Comment: @NuttyProgrammer Reset all fields when you are opening modal because there are several exit points as you mentioned but It has only one entry point.

Comment: @SatyamKoyani But how will I reset the fields of a particular controller if the opening modal link is outside that controller scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular BootstrapUI [`$modal`](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal) service call returns an object with property `result` which is "a promise that is resolved when a modal is closed and rejected when a modal is dismissed". Closing modal by clicking outside of the popup is considered rejection of this promise. It means that in your case you need to call `resetForm` in reject callback of the promise. For example:

```
$modal.open({
    template: 'form.html',
    controller: 'formController'
})
.result.then(function() {
    alert('resolved')
}, function() {
    $scope.resetForm();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

To use scope in this instance, you'll need the buttons ng-click within the ng-controller that it relates to. The alternative is using JavaScript if you *cant* do this.

Have a look at a question I asked yesterday :) it may be helpful if you're using angular-UI

[AngularJS $modalInstance - Can i do this in one controller?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29461449/3540472)

Answer (score 0):

you can use little code of jQuery in controller

$('#id').val(' ')

Worked for Me..

Comment: I agree with augmenting AngularJS with JQuery but only when absolutely necessary. What about if there were 20 fields in the form? Likely, letting model binding work its magic is mostly preferable.

Comment: Yep, I will prefer to use angularjs binding. using jquery or js will be my last resort.

Comment: Actually you can't,you cannot access scope variable outside the controller.
or you can reassign the same controller for button you are using to open modal